# Unexplained parseInt() behavior

Tags: javascript, html

I'm beginning to teach myself `JavaScript` via HeadFirst JavaScript, and I've hit a little bit of a snag. The chapter I'm doing focuses on handling input of data into forms. When I try to use the `updateOrder()` function, the `parseInt()` returns `NaN`, but the alert statements I've put in print the correct values. When I substitute "0" for "" in the value parts of the HTML code, I then get the correct behavior. This leads me to believe that a null character is being prepended to the input.

**Update:** It's late, and I should know better than to be typing code right now. I believe I have fixed all of the typos, and the code is as I have it in my sandbox run. I also want to than @imEnCoded for the edit contribution. Now that the typos are fixed, the original problem I posted about should present correctly.

**My questions are:**

- Am I doing something wrong (Minus some formatting changes, my code
  is exactly as how it is in the book)?
- Is there any way to get around this? I've seen one post on here
  that suggests using regular expressions to filter out any before
  characters, but I was kind of hoping for something cleaner.

For brevity, I've only included what I've determined to be the troublesome code here, but I will link the full solution code too.

[Full HTML and JS for solution is here](https://resources.oreilly.com/examples/9780596527747/blob/master/ch02/donuts3_IE.html)

**The JavaScript part:**

```
function updateOrder(){
    var TAXRATE=0.0925;
    var DONUTPRICE=0.50;
    var numCakeDonuts=parseInt(document.getElementById("cakedonuts")
                              .value);
    var numGlazedDonuts=parseInt(document.getElementById("glazeddonuts")
                              .value);

    if(isNaN(numCakeDonuts)||isNaN(numGlazedDonuts)){
       //alerts put by me to see what is actually held by variables
       //after parsing
       alert("Number of cake donuts is: "+numCakeDonuts);
       alert("Number of glazed donuts is: "+numGlazedDonuts);
       numCakeDonuts=0;
       numGlazedDonuts=0;
    }

        //...rest of code for function here
 }
```

and the given HTML that intakes the values is:

```
 <!--There's some non-troublesome HTML before this section-->
   <div>
     Number of cake donuts:<input type="text" id="cakedonuts" 
                            name="cakedonuts" value="" 
                            onchange="updateOrder();"/>
   </div>

  <div>
     Number of glazed donuts:<input type="text" id="glazeddonuts"
     name="glazeddonuts" value="" onchange="updateOrder();"/>
  </div>
<!--And some after-->
```

Comment: `if(isNaN(numCakeDonuts)||isNaN(numGlazedDonuts){` - misssing `)`

Comment: And `name="cakedonuts` should be `name="cakedonuts"`.

Comment: Repitition of Ids which is conventionally wrong

Comment: `var numCakeDonuts=parseInt(document.getElementById("cakedonuts")
                              .value) || 0;` or  `var numCakeDonuts=parseInt(document.getElementById("cakedonuts")
                              .value); numCakeDonuts = numCakeDonuts ? numCakeDonuts : 0;`

Comment: Always include the radix `10` as the second argument to `parseInt`, or use `Number` instead.

Comment: With regards to the typos, I apologize. Will fix those now.
As for the radix, the text from which I'm learning didn't have it. I read some documentation though from Mozilla which gives that the radix is assumed to be base 10. I take it from now on, include that kind of thing as a matter of course?

Comment: @PranavCBalan How would your suggestion work? While the "or" expression would put in a number, given what I said in my post, it would ALWAYS put in 0. 

The second suggestion is what's already in the code (I indented the ".value" part to be aligned with the rest of the code), and the ternary expression suffers from the same problem as the "or" expression.

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt : Sorry, tried to copy and paste the fields to save typing and missed changing the Id's. I fixed the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is when onChange event trigger on the first input the other input remains empty. and

```
parseInt('') // NaN
```

What you can do is to coerce the input values to number before sending them to `parseInt` function.

```
var numCakeDonuts=parseInt(+document.getElementById("cakedonuts")
                          .value);
var numGlazedDonuts=parseInt(+document.getElementById("glazeddonuts")
                          .value);
```

The `+` sign above will coerce the value it is operating on to a number .It works because `+` operator will coerce empty string to `0`. So empty string input will be converted to `0` before going into `parseInt` function

```
+"" // 0
parseInt(+"") // 0
```

One gotcha will be `+` operator will coerce to NaN if there is any string character in the value.

```
 +'34abc' // NaN
```

For safety purpose you can pass an optional value for each of them in case any of them is coerced to NaN by `+` operator

```
var numCakeDonuts=parseInt(+document.getElementById("cakedonuts")
                          .value) || 0;
var numGlazedDonuts=parseInt(+document.getElementById("glazeddonuts")
                          .value) || 0;
```

Comment: Ah! Ok. Thank you for that. I'll keep that in mind from now, and look into the number() function as I've heard that's another way too. I was focusing on parseInt() since that was what was presented to me in the text, and hate not knowing why code isn't working.

Thank you very much.

Comment: @AgentJ Number() function is quite unforgiving than parseInt(). If unwillingly an string is passed along with the number then Number() will return NaN. Number('12g') // NaN... on the other hand parseInt('12g') will strip off the string from the parameter and will return 12 instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed `)` near `if(isNaN(numCakeDonuts)||isNaN(numGlazedDonuts))`and `"` in `Html`

The variable `numCakedonuts` name also incorrect the corrected line will be:

```
alert("Number of cake donuts is: "+numCakeDonuts);
```

The `d` will be `D`.

```js
function updateOrder(){
    var TAXRATE=0.0925;
    var DONUTPRICE=0.50;
    var numCakeDonuts= parseInt(document.getElementById("cakedonuts")
                              .value);
    var numGlazedDonuts=parseInt(document.getElementById("glazeddonuts")
                              .value);

    if(isNaN(numCakeDonuts)||isNaN(numGlazedDonuts)){
       //alerts put by me to see what is actually held by variables
       //after parsing
       alert("Number of cake donuts is: "+ numCakeDonuts);
       alert("Number of glazed donuts is: "+numGlazedDonuts);
       numCakeDonuts=0;
       numGlazedDonuts=0;
    }

        //...rest of code for function here
 }
```

```html
<!--There's some non-troublesome HTML before this section-->
   <div>
     Number of cake donuts:<input type="text" id="cakedonuts" 
                            name="cakedonuts" value="" 
                            onchange="updateOrder();"/>
   </div>

  <div>
     Number of glazed donuts:<input type="text" id="glazeddonuts"
     name="glazeddonuts" value="" onchange="updateOrder();"/>
  </div>
<!--And some after-->
```

Comment: I just went through your suggestion line by line against what I posted above. I'm not trying to be dense, but how are the two different?